# react js align div horizontally after fetching API

Tags: html, css, reactjs, alignment

i have this code that fetches data from a data base using an api (using Axios)
it keeps looping till the table is over.
it returns data and displays them as cards.
my cards are showing vertically i need them to align horizontally.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import { Table } from 'reactstrap';


import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import CameraIcon from '@material-ui/icons/PhotoCamera';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';


const useStyles = theme => ({
  icon: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  heroContent: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    padding: theme.spacing(8, 0, 6),
  },
  heroButtons: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(4),
  },
  cardGrid: {
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(8),
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(8),
  },
  card: {
    height: '100%',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  cardMedia: {
    paddingTop: '56.25%', // 16:9
  },
  cardContent: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  footer: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    padding: theme.spacing(6),
  },
});



class Cards extends Component{
  state = {
    cards:[],
    user:[],
  }
componentWillMount(){

  axios.get('/getByUsernameAndPassword/' + sessionStorage.getItem('username') + '/' + sessionStorage.getItem('password')).then((response) => {
    if(response.data != null)
    {
      this.setState({
        user: response.data
      })
      sessionStorage.setItem('name', this.state.user.name);
      sessionStorage.setItem('lastname', this.state.user.lastname);
    }
  })

  axios.get('/getCardsByUser/' + sessionStorage.getItem('username')).then((response) => {
    if(response.data != null)
    {
      this.setState({
        cards: response.data
      })
    }
  })
}
render(){
  const { classes } = this.props;
  let cards = this.state.cards.map((card) => {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
      <CssBaseline />
      <main>
        <Container className={classes.cardGrid} maxWidth="md">
          <Grid container spacing={4}>
              <Grid item key={card} xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
                <Card className={classes.card}>
                  <CardMedia
                    className={classes.cardMedia}
                    image="https://source.unsplash.com/random"
                    title="Image title"
                  />
                  <CardContent className={classes.cardContent}>
                    <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                      {card.cardnumber}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography>
                      {card.cardholdername}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography>
                      {card.balance} {card.creditlimit}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography>
                      {card.cvv}
                    </Typography>
                  </CardContent>
                  <CardActions>
                    <Button size="small" color="primary">
                      View
                    </Button>
                    <Button size="small" color="primary">
                      Edit
                    </Button>
                  </CardActions>
                </Card>
              </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Container>
      </main>
    </React.Fragment>
    )
  });
  return(
    <div className="App container">
      <h1>Welcome {sessionStorage.getItem('name') + " " + sessionStorage.getItem('lastname')}</h1>
      {cards}
    </div>
  );
}
}
export default withStyles(useStyles)(Cards);
```

[image: img]

i need the cards to be aligned horizontally...

Comment: Remove react.fragment it is recommended for main tag. Look at google some card styles for react native

Comment: i tried the same code without the api call it aligned perfectly..
and im using reactJS
@NijatAliyev

Comment: Add key index for react.fragment. For map function each card must have unique key

Comment: Sorry i did not really understand im kinda new to react .
can you please send me a code sample of what you meant?
@NijatAliyev

Comment: Add style display: flex; flex-direction: row; div.appcontainer too...

Comment: where should i add it ...
@NijatAliyev

Comment: div className="appContainer" style={{ styles here... }}

Comment: thank you ! i will try that